# plugin development: problem with functions

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

I have this very basic scheme to build my first plugin, but now I have one problem:
when I put a hook to add_action on point 1 works, but i need to get the color from shortcode function, so, when i put the code at point 2 don't works.

```
        class myclass
        {
             public function init()
             {
                  global $shortcode_tags;
                      add_shortcode( MYSHORTCODE, array( 'myclass', 'shortcode' ) );
                              // * point 1
                  return;

             }

             public function shortcode( )
             {
                 // want to run add_action here
                             // i need to get the color from shortcode that part is done
                             // question is how i can run add_action from here and pass
                             // the variable to function globalcolor (point 3), then run it in wp_head?
                             // * point 2
             } 

             function globalcolor($color)
             {
                             echo '<style>body{color:' .$color . '}</style>' . "\n";
                             // * point 3
             }
        }

        add_action( 'init', array( 'myclass', 'init', ) );            


the code to add: add_action( 'wp_head', array( 'myclass', 'globalcolor' ) );
```

Any ideas? and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: For reference: See the [same question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844385/wordpress-plugin-and-wp-head).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is you are using static [callbacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) while you should be passing on the object so you have access to your class properties.

You can fire off the initialization like this:

```
class Myclass {

  public function __construct() {
    // Object method call, instead of a static one
    add_action('init', array($this, 'init'));
  }

  public function init() {
    // add_shortcode(...);
  }

}

// Trigger constructor
new Myclass;
```

On another note, instead of hard-coding styles in the `<head>`, you may prefer to customize the body classes instead. The filter `body_class` is available for that ([related example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15850/remove-classes-from-body-class)).