# How to apply style to the body tag of a particular page?

Tags: conditional-tags

I have the following code:

```
<?php
 if ((is_home()) OR (!is_single()) OR (!is_page('171'))) : ?>
    <body>
<?php else: ?>
    <body class="last-page">
<?php endif; ?>
```

However it doesn't seem to work as expected. I want the class "last-page" to be applied to the body of the page with the id of 171 and pages that display single posts. If I take the third condition out, the "last-page" class is applied correctly to single post pages but with the third condition there it doesn't get applied to any of the two.

I want the "last-page" class to be applied to both single post pages and page 171.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Consider using the `body_class` filter for this: [related example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15850/remove-classes-from-body-class/15878).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your verbal desription, i would think this should work:

```
<?php  if ( is_single() OR is_page('171') ) : ?>
<body class="last-page"> 
<?php else: ?>     
<body>
<?php endif; ?>
```